# Scala generic type constraints and specialized behavior

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics

I have a class where I need an `apply[T]` method where `T` is only allowed to be `Foo` or `Bar`. Also, the method needs to behave differently depending on whether it is a `Foo` or a `Bar`. Becuase of type erasure, I cannot simple make `apply[Foo]` and `apply[Bar]` methods (that was my first attempt). To solve this, I tried doing something like this

```
def apply[T](ds: Dataset[T]): Dataset[T] = { 
    ds match {
        case ds: Dataset[Foo] => ...
        case ds: Dataset[Bar] => ...
        case _ => ???
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work because of type erasure of `T`. Also this doesn't even restrict this method to only be able to be called with `T` of type `Foo` or `Bar`, it just "does nothing" when it isn't of one of those two types. How can I make this apply method have these properties?

Thank you.

Comment: NB: it does not "do nothing" when the type is wrong as written, it'll throw a `NotImplementedError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice trick around type erasure:

```
def apply(ds: Dataset[Foo]): Dataset[Foo] = ???
def apply(ds: Dataset[Bar])(implicit dummy: DummyImplicit): Dataset[Bar] = ???
```

Lets you have multiple methods with the same run-time signature without having to use type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an implicit typeclass:

```
trait Baz[T] {
  def apply(ds: DataSet[T]): DataSet[T]
}

implicit val fooImpl = new Baz[Foo] {
  def apply(ds: DataSet[Foo]): DataSet[Foo] = ???
}

implicit val barImpl = new Baz[Bar] {
  def apply(ds: DataSet[Bar]): DataSet[Bar] = ???
}

def apply[T](ds: Dataset[T])(implicit b: Baz[T]): Dataset[T] = b(ds)
```

Comment: You'd still need to know the exact type of `T` in order to associate with the right instance of the typeclass at the call site at compile time